# grep multiple strings at once in specific occurrence

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I would like to `grep` the following string in exact order.

`x*/\*y\*/\*z\*/\*w\*`

how can I do it?

`grep x*/\*y\*/\*z\*/\*w\* <file>` -> does not work

**Example input**

```
xvg/cyv/dgzfdre/rwt 
avg/cyv/dgzfdre/rwt 
x/y/z/w
```

**Desired output**

```
xvg/cyv/dgzfdre/rwt 
x/y/z/w
```

Comment: Are those stars part of the string? Then you need to escape them by backslashes as they have a special meaning in search patterns

Answer (score 1):

This achieves what you appear to require.

```
$ cat testfile
xvg/cyv/dgzfdre/rwt
avg/cyv/dgzfdre/rwt
x/y/z/w
$ grep 'x.*/.*y.*/.*z.*/.*w' testfile
xvg/cyv/dgzfdre/rwt
x/y/z/w
$
```

Your `grep x*/\*y\*/\*z\*/\*w\* <file>` does not work as it's looking for zero or more `x` characters followed by a `/`, followed by a `*` character, followed immediately by a `y` character [etc].

Comment: Thx! it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`*`s are magic characters in regular expressions that mean 'zero or more of the preceding item'.  You need to escape them:

```
grep 'x\*/\*y\*/\*z\*/\*w\*' /path/to/file
```

Comment: did not work :(      
I created a file with the following stalemates    

xvg/cyv/dgzfdre/rwt    
avg/cyv/dgzfdre/rwt    
x/y/z/w    

I accept it to grep line #1 and #3 and it did not catch anything

Comment: @Dor So actually the stars are not part of the string, but wildcards. But beware: Grep uses regex patterns, unlike the pattern matching in the shell, so if you want to match any string, use `.*`. The point is for "any char", the star for "the preceding atom repeated". Read `man 7 regex`